# what quantum computing simulator can achieve drag-and-drop programing fuction without internet like IBM web composer?

Tags: qiskit, programming, quantum-state, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

[image]

I reallt need some kind of simulator can work like this.Quirk is similar but also require internet.can anyone know how to achieve this?It is very important for some eaducational lesson to students.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Quirk can work without internet connection.
Just click on *Export* button and choose the "offline copy" option. You will get a single file which contains Quirk and can run from your local machine without internet connection.

[image]

Comment: oh,thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with the `Circuit Composer widget`

```
from ibm_quantum_widgets import CircuitComposer
editor = CircuitComposer()
editor
```

[image: Result]

More info [here](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/lab/docs/iql/composer-widget)